# how to stop a loop and printing the last statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created this code in loop however I'm unable to print "Have a nice day" the loop is either stopping right after I enter "Quit" or it keep running with no end. can someone point out to me how can i get to print the sentence "Have a nice day" then exit the loop after that.

[image]

Comment: Try posting your code here rather than an image. Especially because the image is not so clear on indentation.

Answer (score 1):

In `line 23`, you are taking input in `Text2`, and in the if the condition on `line 24`, you are comparing with the variable `text`

**You have to compare Text2 in line 24 to fix this**

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me. everything is running good now.

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help. If you need help in anything else let me know, if everything seems good do mark the question as solved